# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: Connection reset by peer when uploading image to server

Tags: laravel, flutter

Question:
I'm building a Flutter app where users can upload images to a server. I'm using the ImagePicker plugin to allow users to select images from the gallery, and then I'm trying to upload the selected image to the server using the http package.

However, when I attempt to upload the image, I encounter the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: Connection reset by peer.

I've checked my server, and it seems to be up and running fine. I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to troubleshoot it.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Function to select an image from the gallery and show it in a dialog
Future<void> selectGalleryPhoto(BuildContext context) async {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    imageQuality: 50,
    maxWidth: 500,
    maxHeight: 500,
  );

  if (pickedFile != null) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 200),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 120,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: Image.file(
                        File(pickedFile.path),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: 240,
                        height: 240,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Profile.uploadImage(pickedFile);
                    },
                    child: Text('Upload'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.close),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// Function to upload the selected image to the server
static Future<void> uploadImage(XFile image) async {
  final token = await FetchUserData.headers();
  String url = 'http://www.demosite.org/api/ImageUpdate/';
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
  request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', image.path));
  var response = await request.send();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Image uploaded successfully');
  } else {
    print('Image upload failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

I've added the necessary dependencies for image_picker and http in my pubspec.yaml, and the code seems fine to me. However, I keep getting the "Connection reset by peer" error. I'm not sure what's causing this issue or how to fix it.

Any help or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you read anything from `File(image.path)`?

Comment: if (pickedFile != null) {
    showDialog();} Works well

Comment: console:  "D/MediaScannerConnection( 3040): Scanned /data/user/0/com.example.my_app/cache/daf02516-83dd-46ed-b29e-3d9f8e49ba447887501012916390524.jpg to null
I/flutter ( 3040): Image upload failed with status: 301"

Comment: I'd focus on the 301 error.  Is the server trying to redirect you to another page?  Should you be using https instead of http for the page you are posting to?

Comment: Yes File(pickedFile.path) showing image @pskink

Comment: Yes@JohnWeidner